# Create Shopify checkout Redirect URL after login

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I want to make my own checkout experience in shopify website so I am building a sales channel app for processing the checkout which is similar to boldcommerce cashier app.

Now when any customer click on the checkout button , it should open customer login page(if they are not logged in ) after logged in should be redirect to our sales channel app.

But it is not happening right now, it always redirect to shopify default checkout page.

Please help on this. how I can resolve this.?

Comment: What have you fried so far?

Comment: I have created sales channel and able to read the cart information.now need to move checkout process.